# Alternative to Horizontal Scroll View in android

Tags: android

In my application i have to show large number of images in horizontal scroll view. All these images comes from my server only. My problem is i can't use adapter pattern with Horizontal scroll view. Is there any API to solve this. Like Horizontal scroll view with custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RecylerView API. It is more sophisticated. You can list the items vertically or horizontally using the LayoutManager.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with horizontal LinearLayoutManager
or [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please use **recycler view** for this , This is easy and very efficient.

First of all create Recycler view  [LINK](http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example)

Then set layout param as

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            rvListed.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

For more Documentation Please read  [Android Developer Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)